# Are foreign scenes meant to have no translation in Overlord?

Tags: overlord

Recently saw [Overlord](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4530422/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1) in a non-english country. While the English parts were subbed, the German and French dialogues were not. Instead, subtitles just said something like

> [Speaking French]

We saw the movie anyway, and the story can still be followed, but are those scenes not meant to have translations?

Comment: And if that is the intention of the movie ... what do they do when the movie shows in France?

Comment: @BrettFromLA Fun fact: Mad Max's Fury Road used German instead of Russian for foreign dialogue when aired in Russia ^^

Comment: There have also been cases where the movie's plot was straight up spoiled by untranslated foreign dialogue (for people who could understand what was being said.)  Example: the first [Iron Man (2008)](https://www.looper.com/7776/movies-huge-spoilers-hiding-plain-sight/) - (Note: other entries on that blog are not so relevant, just the first, Iron Man.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I lost a big chunk of the movie! It seems that French dialogue is subtitled, but German is not.

[image]

This is possibly to emulate the perspective of Boyce, who speaks French and English, and so understands only those two languages.